# sj latex example files not compiling using miktex 23.10.12

Tags: texdoc, stata

I am trying to write a latex file using a Stata do file in order to include my Stata workings.

I am using the texdoc and sjlatex package. For understanding the procedure, I followed [this](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/pdf/10.1177/1536867X1601600201) article.

However, the loaded example file is not getting compiled. I am using Miktex 23.10.12.

Specifically, the following is the code of the example tex file.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{stata}
\begin{document}

\section*{Exercise 1}
Open the 1978 Automobile Data and summarize the variables.

\begin{stlog}\input{example1_1.log.tex}\end{stlog}

\section*{Exercise 2}
Run a regression of price on milage and weight.

\begin{stlog}\input{example1_2.log.tex}\end{stlog}

\end{document}
```

I have got the two mentioned log files in the tex format within the working directory.

I am in the working directory where I have installed the sjlatex files.

On compiling I am getting the following error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.51 \ifluatex
```

Here the l.51 is the line in the stata.sty file.

I have already tried updating my MikTex distribution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do not link to a long external resource. Show a small example what you are doing here. That makes it much easier to test your issue.

Comment: \ifluatex is defined in the iftex package so you are probably missing \usepackage{iftex} but I didn't check your external links

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks for your response. I have edited the question to make it more clear.

Comment: Do as @DavidCarlisle suggested: add \usepackage{iftex} before your stata package.

Comment: Thanks @DavidCarlisle . Adding \usepacakge{iftex} before stata pakage works. However, I think the better solution is to change the stata.sty file. Right before the \iftex (line 51) I added \ReqiurePackage{iftex}. This makes my stata tex code shorter.

Comment: isnt stata.sty a standard package coming with Stata? if so you should not edit it but report it to the maintainers to fix upstream. @PallakGoyal

Comment: You are right @DavidCarlisle. I think the sjlatex package the provides stata.sty is maintained by the Stata Journal. A basic internet search did not tell me how I can report the error to the maintainers. If you can tell me that, I shall report it asap.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to add:
`\RequirePackage{iftex}`
right before line 51 in the `stata.sty` file that gets installed into the working directory on installing sjlatex.

Otherwise in each of the tex code in the stata do file an additional line `\usepackage{iftex}` must be added before `\usepackage{stata}`. (Credits: David Carlisle)